# Parallel commands / file transfer on persistent single ssh connection

Tags: unix, file-upload, ssh, file-transfer, openssh

I have SSH connection created like:

```
ssh -MNf -S /tmp/mysocket user@host
```

And I'm using ssh without password for this session. I want to run multiple parallel commands (for example: 500 parallel commands) on the same connection and i want to copy files at the same time by using this persistent ssh socket, 
so i can run commands with:

```
ssh -S /tmp/mysocket user@host md5sum file102 | cut -d " " -f 1
```

some times i get "Connection refused" warning but actually command works, i see multiple connections with "netstat -an" I understand that commands are not working on the same connection...

```
aokan-pc:~ $ netstat -an |grep ESTABLISHED |grep '192.168.1.30:22'
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.29:58568         192.168.1.30:22           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.29:60866         192.168.1.30:22           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.29:60385         192.168.1.30:22           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.29:60368         192.168.1.30:22           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.29:52523         192.168.1.30:22           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.29:42096         192.168.1.30:22           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.29:42177         192.168.1.30:22           ESTABLISHED
```

1) 
Is it possible to run parallel commands on 1 persistent openssh connection? How?

2) 
Can I transfer multiple parallel files to the same remote host on 1 persistent ssh connection/socket?  And I have to use a checksum system, I tried to use md5sum for checksum controls... (with rsync or with scp (using multiple connections) or with nfs how?)

3) 
What are disadvantages of using single socket connection for this job? Instead of using one Should i use thousands of TCP socket connections to the same host?